Add examples to the "What topics can I ask about here?" page
I notice that the What topics can I ask about here? page does not* provide examples for what is on-topic. (* as of the time that I am writing this.)  Other stack exchange sites typically list dozens of positive (appropriate) and negative (inappropriate) examples of subject matter and provide extensive guidance.
There are many questions on this meta site asking about what is on topic and off topic on the main site.  I'm sure an aggregate summary of those discussions would be a good way to seed content for the page.
I think it would be helpful to add examples to flesh out that page.

This site is quite liberal with regard to this question. Essentially any answerable question concerning constructed languages of any kind is on-topic here, including translation requests or single word requests. In my experience as a moderator, off-topic questions aren't a problem yet, and there are no recurring patterns of off-topic questions. When we have to close questions, it is often the criterion "opinion based" that is decisive, not being off-topic.
If you have a question on constructed languages, go forth and ask it.
